# How to retrieve exchange rate between two currency

Tags: sql-server

I have two sql tables Ccy that maintain currency information which is following
[image]

and another table is ccyRate that maintain Exchange Rate information which is following [image]

The second table shows the Ex-Rate from specified currency to Local currency which is on base 1

now what I want is that how to find Ex-Rate between USD and PKR from ccyRate table using sql select statement and I have tried the following code but not getting my result

```
select 
     case when crt_From = 'USD' then 1  else 0 end / crt_ToLocalCcy,
     case when crt_From = 'PKR' then 1  else 0 end / crt_ToLocalCcy
from CcyRate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a division:

```
select 
  (select crt_ToLocal from CcyRate where crt_Code = 'USD') /
  (select crt_ToLocal from CcyRate where crt_Code = 'PKR') as USDtoPKR
```

Comment: Thank, it work by adding top 1 but how to handle if currency is AFN which is local currency

Comment: What do you need to handle? 78 and 0.543 are the rates from AFN to USD and PKR respectively right?

Comment: Yes, and I think I solve that problem too by adding one more record AFN = 1 to table exchange rate